# How to ignore special characters when incrementing and how to use % to loop through ASCII?

Tags: c, encryption, ascii, modulus, rot13

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char msg[31] = {'\0'};
    char encrypted[31] = {'\0'};
    int key;


    printf("Please enter a message under 30 characters: ");
    fgets(msg, 31, stdin);

    printf("Please enter an encryption key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    int i = 0;

    if (msg[i] && (('a' >= msg[i] && msg[i]>= 'z') || ('A' >= msg[i] && msg[i] >= 'Z')))
    {
        i++;
    } else {

    while (msg[i] && (('a' <= msg[i] && msg[i]<= 'z') || ('A' <= msg[i] && msg[i] <= 'Z')))
{
    encrypted[i] = (msg[i] + key);
    i++;
}
    }

    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%d\n", key);
    printf("%s\n", encrypted);

}
```

I've got my code to work but i don't know how to make the incrementing ignore special characters and spaces. Also how do i use % to loop back to 'a' and 'A' to keep all the capitalization in the message the same?

Comment: Edit that into your question - it's useless in a comment.

Comment: `'a' <= msg[i] <= 'z'` and `'A' < msg[i] < 'Z'` probably don't do what you expect.  Edit:  Wait - I already told you that on a comment on one of your other questions.  Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: sorry hold on, thats my old code

Comment: Have a look at `ctype.h`, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do range tests like this:

```
'a' <= msg[i] <= 'z'
```

This evaluates as `'a' <= msg[i]` becomes true or false (1 or 0), which is always less than `'z'`.

So to start you need:

```
( msg[i] >= 'a' && msg[i] <= 'z' || msg[i] >= 'A' && msg[i] <= 'Z' )
```

Now, you have put this condition on your loop, so it will terminate as soon as you encounter a special character.  If you want to have different behaviour for letters, check them inside the loop:

```
for( i = 0; msg[i] != 0; i++ ) {
    if( msg[i] >= 'a' && msg[i] <= 'z' || msg[i] >= 'A' && msg[i] <= 'Z' ) {
        encrypted[i] = msg[i] + key;
    } else {
        encrypted[i] = msg[i];
    }
}
```

Now the second part of your question.  You appear to want to rotate your letters.  Try this:

```
// Sanity -- to avoid overflowing `char`
key %= 26;
while( key < 0 ) key += 26;

for( i = 0; msg[i] != 0; i++ ) {
    if( msg[i] >= 'a' && msg[i] <= 'z' ) {
        encrypted[i] = 'a' + ((msg[i]-'a' + key) % 26);
    } else if( msg[i] >= 'A' && msg[i] <= 'Z' ) {
        encrypted[i] = 'A' + ((msg[i]-'A' + key) % 26);
    } else {
        encrypted[i] = msg[i];
    }
}
```

If you don't want non-letters in the encrypted string at all, then make another index:

```
int e = 0;

   encrypted[e++] = etc;  // Only when you want to add something to the string.
```

And don't forget after the loop:

```
encrypted[e] = 0;   // terminate string.
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!! If it wouldn't be too much to ask, could you explain it slightly please. just the %= bit and encrypted[i] = 'a' + ((msg[i]-'a' + key) % 26); and the elseif statement. Thanks. Sorry im a bit of a noob. Just started programming and trying to learn.

Comment: You subtract the first letter of the range, so `'a'` becomes `0`.  Your letters are now numbered 0 to 25.  Then you add the key and take modulo by 26 so that it remains in the range 0 to 25.  Finally, you add `'a'` back on to make it the correct character again.  You operate on the lower- and uppercase ranges individually.